# How can I chance the color of a cell(s) after a list item has been chose in the same row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to change, say cells A1 and C1 to a specific color when a specific drop-down list item is chosen on cell C1.

I do not want my chosen item to effect any other cells aside from A1 and C1, when C1 is changed, but would like to able to scale this formula to cover the entire sheet - say if I want to change the colors of A3 and C3, only after the appropriate drop-down list item was chosen on C3.

Thank you!

Comment: Check [Use formulas with conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I made an easy sample. I did a dataset like this:

[image]

In Column C there is a dropdown list that allows 2 options: YES or NO. If YES is select, then cells from same row but columns A and C will highlight in yellow.

If i change the value in C, colors changes:

[image]

To make this work, I created a Conditional Formatting rule based on next formula:

`=IF($C2="YES";TRUE;FALSE)`

**UPDATE**: When using formulas in Conditional Formatting rules, you don't need a formula like mine that specifically returns a True/False value. Typing a condition would be enough, and if that condition is met, that would be equal to a True Value, and the formatting would be applied.

So in this case, would be perfectly right if you type your condition like this:
`=$C2="YES"`

And the application area where this Conditional Formatting Rule must be applied is:

`=$A$2:$A$7;$C$2:$C$7`

Yes, I excluded column B or it would be highlighted too.

To create a Conditional Formating Rule, check [Use formulas with conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right and it would work for sure, but I got a bad habit of making this kind of formulas this way, trying to get a boolean value, because for my head is easier to *construct* a formula where final result must be a True/False value that just typing a condition. But as I said, I got that habit.

Comment: Sorry this might be a stupid question but where would i put the first formula part ( =IF($C2="YES";TRUE;FALSE) ) and where would I put the second part ( =$A$2:$A$7;$C$2:$C$7 )? Thanks

Comment: @ZachariaSalad, you might want to read this [Use formulas with conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)